# Directly connect OpenStack Instance to VLAN with static IP

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

In migrating workloads from VMWare to OpenStack, we have some legacy instances that we need to handle. These instances are directly connected to a VLAN in the Physical network (without a router in VMWare) and have static IP addresses assigned through the OS itself.

We will be using Geneve for tenant networks, and this setup is working fine, but some instances needs to be able to directly communicate with other infrastructure on the VLAN.

So far I've tried to create provider networks connected to the VLAN through a trunk port. This will automatically assign an IP address to the instance, which is unwanted. I've also tried to add a fixed IP.

What would be the correct way of migrating these to OpenStack? Any input is appreciated.